# Decryption is not working with AES 128 bit CBC in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a token with the `AES 128 bit CBC` encryption in PHP.
If I try to encrypt and decrypt a token, the result is not the original token.
Here is my code:

```
$decrKey = "123456789abcdefg";
$decrIV = "xyz123456789abcd";

function encryptAES($data,$key,$iv)
{
$decr= mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_encode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);    
return $decr;   
}    

function decryptAES($data,$key,$iv)
{
$decr= mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);    
return $decr;   
}      

$token = "abcdefghijk";
echo $token;

$tokenEncrypt = encryptAES($token,$decrKey,$decrIV);
echo "encrypt: ".$tokenEncrypt ;

$tokenDecrypt = decryptAES($tokenEncrypt,$decrKey,$decrIV);
echo "decrypt: ".$tokenDecrypt ;
```

What do i miss?

Comment: Note that PHP mcrypt does not perform PKCS#7 padding (check the comments for `mcrypt_encrypt` so your function will only work if data is text, not if it is binary (and ends with one or more `00` valued bytes). In short `mcrypt` has not been developed for years and PHP mcrypt is rather crap - unfortunately there are few good alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should base 64 encode the result of the encryption method (called the ciphertext), and decode it again before decryption. You are currently base 64 encoding the plain text in the encryption function instead of the ciphertext. Encoding the plain text is not necessary. It would be however a good idea to use a well defined [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding) for the plain text.

```
$encr = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
return $encr
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! `use a well defined character-encoding for the plain text` The text I need to encode/decode are _OAuth Token_. Do you think that a character encoding is necessary for them? If so, how to add it?

Comment: It seems that OAuth uses ASCII and UTF-8. As ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 you should be safe when applying [this method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) to the plain text. I'll leave it to you to place the decoding function at the right spot :)

Comment: The encrypted token is not the same as the original one. Did I make something wrong with the UTF-8 encode/decode? `// ENCODE:
$oauthToken = utf8_encode($oauthToken);
$oauthToken = encryptAES($oauthToken,$decrKey,$decrIV);

//DECODE:
$oauthToken = utf8_decode($oauthToken);
$oauthToken = decryptAES($oauthToken,$decrKey,$decrIV);
`

Comment: Yes, you did :). You should utf8_decode the *result* of the decryption.